# Overlap between Programmers SE and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, software-engineering-se

I am puzzled by the overlap between Programmers SE and Stack Overflow. I suppose the topic has already undergone a lengthy, heated debate, but I can't resist (re-?)discussing the following specific bullets from the FAQs.

From the FAQ at Programmers:

> This can include topics such as: (snip)
>
> - Practical algorithms and data structures

From the FAQ at Stack Overflow:

> ...but if your question generally covers... (snip)
>
> - A software algorithm

So where do I ask about, say, bubble-sort?

Comment: Also, SO: software tools commonly used by programmers P.SE: Developer tools and techniques

Comment: I had a question that was supposedly migrated to "programmers" today, but it isn't even a programming question - I was looking for information about the movie "Sorting out Sorting". It's not clear to me how that's a question about sorting - while it's a matter that's "unique to the programming profession" (from SO's FAQ), it's not a question about programming itself - it's a question about a movie about programming. Add to that the fact that the "migrated" link leads to a 404 on programmers.sE, and I'm left very confused as to what's going on.

Comment: I always thought that "StackOverflow" was for questions about programming tasks and "Programmers" was more for questions about the developer as a person. For example: What tool you use/prefer for your line of work? (PE) How to use this tool for this task? (SO). Asking for how to implement some algorithm should be SO field. I don't understand the meaning of "Practical algorithms and data structures", and I even less understand how this is PE field.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I end up concluding that I don't see a _real_ need for Programmers SE (or Comp Sci SE, for that matter). The whole thing reeks with SE inflation, generating more specific sites than is useful/appropriate IMHO.

Comment: I see a field for Comp Sci SE: general programing concepts (all the lamba-calculus/functional "novelty", i.e.) and algorithm study (complexity comparison, i.e.).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 13):

If the solution to your problem is likely a **big picture / white board solution involving no or minimal code**, it is a good fit for programmers.

If the solution to your problem involves specific code it is probably a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Example:

> Which sorting algorithm is best for `<specific problem I am having>`?

belongs on Programmers

> How would I implement bubble sort in 8086 assembly?

belongs on Stack Overflow

Comment: Where would you put a question on the computational complexity of bubblesort? No code, but hardly subjective...

Comment: I am pretty sure I would consider your first variant to be perfectly appropriate on SO, and answer away happily without migration to Programmers SE crossing my mind.

Comment: @shog imho ... computational complexity belongs on SO or even the Comp Sci SE ...

Comment: If SO turns into `please-send-me-the-codez` it would be a real shame.

Comment: +1 for "Comp Sci SE" reference.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the distinction between these two sites is currently very blurred. For example, three of my top ten tags on SO are `git`, `svn`, and `version-control`. Since none of these questions deal with actual source code, do they all now belong on P.SE, because of

- Developer tools and techniques

or should they stay on SO because of

- software tools commonly used by programmers

?

From the start of Programmers.SE, I was always under the impression that it was for questions about the *craft* of programming. However, my primary site of focus is SO, so I haven't really been keeping up on P.SE to see how it's changed. But it seems to have changed a *lot* from what I first learned, by the time it now has gone "public". When did "practical algorithms and data structures" become off topic for SO?

Here's how I would modify the P.SE topic list:

- Software engineering
- Developer testing
- <strike>Developer tools and techniques</strike>
- <strike>Practical algorithms and data structures</strike>
- <strike>Design patterns</strike>
- <strike>Architecture</strike>
- Development methodologies
- Quality assurance
- **Learning resources and techniques**
- Software law
- Programming puzzles
- Freelancing and business concerns

Comment: "When did "practical algorithms and data structures" become off topic for SO?" It isn't, unless the question has zero code. If it's a question *with code* about data structures, it belongs on SO.

Comment: I agree with the tools part wholeheartedly, though -- there's no practical way to involve code in developer tools, so I removed that one. I also added the word "concepts" to algorithms and data structures to make it more clear on the whiteboard vs code paradigm.